# Prometheus helm values deployed via Terraform does not load the file specified in file_sd_configs block

Tags: terraform, prometheus, jmx-exporter

I am following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/open-monitoring.html which enables prometheus to grab metrics from MSK Cluster using JMX Exporter

The tutorial mentions to create a targets.json file and populate it with your values later on, you need to load that file with:

```
  - job_name: 'broker'
    file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - 'targets.json'
```

My current prometheus values file looks like this, but seems like I can't load the `targets.json` file into the prometheus configuration

```
extraScrapeConfigs: |
  - job_name: broker
    file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - targets.json
```

Do I need to interpolate something in between for Terraform to recognize this external file?

Specifying the absolute file path does not seem to work.

Comment: It's very hard to tell without seeing the terraform code.

Comment: Hey @MarkoE, the prometheus is deployed using the ``helm_release`` resource in terraform: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to fix this. I've followed this approach:

As you can see I needed to load the `targets.json` file with a ConfigMap resource. These are the helm values I've used for the prometheus chart:

```
extraScrapeConfigs: |
  - job_name: targets
    file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - /etc/prometheus/exports/targets.json
server:
  extraConfigmapMounts: 
    - name: targets
      mountPath: /etc/prometheus/exports
      subPath: ""
      configMap: targetsfile
      readOnly: true
```

The ConfigMap resource gets created as:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "targets" {
  metadata {
    name      = "targetsfile"
    namespace = "monitoring"
  }

  data = {
    "targets.json" = "${file("${path.module}/targets.json")}"
  }

}
```

Following those steps, you can succesfully load into the `prometheus-server` pod the `targets.json` file